# Help with memory allocation for multiplayer game server

Tags: c++

I'm kind of new to C++ development in linux and I'm trying to make a multiplayer game. I know that it is a bit of complex program to start but I have some background on this type of program from other languages so I guess the most difficult part is taming the language.

Although I'm programming a multiplayer game, my doubts are about the best way to handle the memory and avoid leaks in C++.

My doubts are about allocating memory for the client objects and for the game tables. For the client objects I've read that the std containers handle the memory allocation for me. I don't know if this memory is allocated on heap so I've decided to use a map of pointers (with the socket fd as key) to client object. This way, I have something like this when a client connect and disconnect:

Daemon.cpp

```
map<int,Client*> clientList;

//Do server stuff

//Add connected client to list
void onConnect(int socketFd) {
clientList[socketFd] = new Client();
}

//remove connected client from list
void onDisconnect(int socketFd) {
delete clientList[socketFd];
clientList.erase(socketFd);
}
```

The Client class is a simple class that has a virtual destructor, some client parameters (like IP, connected time, etc) and some methods (like send, etc). Is this the best way to keep track of clients without memory problems? I guess I still have to add exceptions handling on new Client() allocations...

The second part, and I guess the most difficult for me, is about the game tables. Clients can enter and leave tables of games. I have a table class with a lot of parameters, constants and methods. I'm creating all the game tables on start up on the same Daemon.cpp described above:

Daemon.cpp

```
GameTable *tables;

int main() {
tables = new Chess[MAX_NUMBER_OF_TABLES];
}
```

Some explanations: GameTable is the base class for all games. It is an interface with base parameters and virtual game functions (like doCommand, addClient, removeClient, etc). Chess class is the implementation of the chess game, it inheritance (sorry bad english) from GameTable. Questions:

1) Is this the best way (memory) to handle it?
2) Chess class has a lot of parameters, when I allocate the table list of Chess objects do the memory for all objects already allocated or I have to allocate and dealocate inside Chess class (with constructors and destructors)?

My third question is how to add and remove clients to/from tables. First I thought in creating a simple vector with clients like:

GameTable.h

```
vector <Client> clientInTable;
```

Chess.cpp

```
//Add client to table
void addClient(Client &client) {
clientInList.push_back(client);
}

//remove client from table
void removeClient(Client &client) {
//search client on list, when found get position pos
clientList.erase(pos);
}
```

Soon I've noticed that when I remove the client its destructor was called. It must not happen! Than I thought in use a vector of pointers like:

GameTable.h

```
vector <Client*> clientInTable;
```

Chess.cpp

```
//Add client to table
void addClient(Client *client) {
clientInList.push_back(client);
}

//remove client from table
void removeClient(Client *client) {
//search client on list, when found get position pos
clientList[pos] = NULL;
}
```

Is this the best way to handle it? Thanks everybody for the help.

Answer (score 3):

Everything that is dynamically allocated should have something that 'owns' the responsibility for deleting it - typically this should be an [auto](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6k3ybftz%28VS.80%29.aspx) allocated struct/classs that uses [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization).

Use smart pointers such as `std::auto_ptr` and `std::tr1::shared_ptr` to store dynamically allocated objects, and use memory managing containers such as `boost::ptr_vector` and `boost::ptr_map` for storing multiple dynamically allocated objects in a single container.

Doing this kind of thing manually is error prone, difficult and, seeing as good solutions already exist, pointless.

---

This:

```
GameTable *tables;

int main() {
tables = new Chess[MAX_NUMBER_OF_TABLES];
}
```

Is extremely dangerous. An array of `Chess` cannot be used interchangeably with an array of `GameTable`. The compiler lets it pass because a pointer to `Chess` can be used as a pointer to a `GameTable`.

Arrays are contiguously packed - if `size_of(Chess)` is different to `size_of(GameTable)`, indexing into the array will result in indexing into the middle of an object possibly followed by an access violation (that's the most likely scenario, you're actually invoking undefined behaviour).

Comment: I'd go beyond saying it's dangerous; It's wrong. If you use the tables array at all you'll end up with corruption.

Comment: Well, what do I do then? How do I create a list (array, vector, whatever) of allocated Chess object (inherited from GameTable)?

Comment: @Akira: change `GameTable *tables;` to `Chess *tables;`.  Or, instead of storing your objects in an array, make your array store only pointers to the objects.

Comment: What you really want is an array of pointers to `GameTable`. You'll then have to allocate each pointer in the array individually as a `Chess`. Start with: `GameTable * tables[MAX_NUMBER_OF_TABLES];`. Then in main have a for loop over each element of the array that calls `new` like this: `tables[i] = new Chess();` Don't forget that you'll eventually have to call `delete` for each of these objects.

Comment: Use a container of pointers - a `boost::ptr_vector<GameTable>` would be my choice.

Answer (score 1):

Using smart pointers is a good way to avoid memory leaks

Consider boost ones:
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/smart_ptr/smart_ptr.htm

Answer (score 0):

A good strategy would be to set statically the maximum number of clients that can be managed by your server.

Then you build all Client objects required to manage all the clients from start (in an array or vector).
You will then re-use Client objects when there is a new connection, end using one when the client disconnects.

That require that your Client object is made in a way that allow reuse : the initialization and "termination" of it's use have to be explicit functions (init() and end() for example, something similar).

When you can, allow from start all resources you will ever need and reuse the objects. That way you limit memory fragmentation and get faster to the "worst case".

Comment: Indeed. Work with classes that take in certainties as their constructor arguments, such as 'number of players' and so on, and keep hierarchically doing this as they get reach towards playing the game.

Answer (score 0):

Inside `onDisconnect`, I would recommend calling `clientList[socketFd] = NULL;` after the connection is destroyed.  This would make sure you aren't keeping an already-freed pointer around which can open up the door for problems later.  This may already be handled by your `clientList.erase` method, but I thought I'd mention it just in case.

There might be a problem with the way you declared your `Chess` array.  The pointer `tables` is defined as a pointer-to-`GameTable`, but it is pointing to an array of `Chess` objects.  If a `Chess` object is nothing more than a `GameTable` object with a different name, then this code should work.  However, if the definition of `Chess` adds anything to itself after it inherits from `GameTable` then you will change the size of the object and you will not be able to iterate through the array with that pointer.  For example, if `sizeof(GameTable)` is 16 bytes and `sizeof(Chess)` is 24 bytes (perhaps due to some added member data), then `tables[1]` will refer to a memory location in the middle of the first `Chess` object in the array, not the beginning of the second item in the array as intended.  Polymorphism lets you treat a derived class as if it were an object of its parent's class for the sake of using inherited members, but it's not safe to cast a pointer to a derived type into a pointer to the parent type for the sake of accessing an array.

Regarding adding clients to tables, can a client be associated with more than one table at a time?  If not, give each table a unique ID of some sort and give each client a field called (for instance) `current_table`.  When the client joins a table, store that table's ID in the field.  When the client leaves the table, zero out the value.  If a client can join multiple tables, this field can be turned into an array (`current_tables[MAX_TABLES_PER_CLIENT]`) and treated similarly.

Alternatively, you can create something like:

```
struct mapping {
    clientId_t client_id;
    tableId_t table_id;
};

struct mapping client_table_map[MAX_NUM_CLIENT_TABLE_MAPS] = {0};
```

When a client joins a table, create a new mapping structure containing the unique IDs of the client and table and add it to the list.  Delete the entry when the client disconnects from the table.  Now, you will have a table of all current connections that you can cross-reference in either direction (find all clients using a table or find all tables in use by a client).

Comment: Thanks for the input. Indeed a client can only be associated with one table. I've already thought in adding the table ID to the client object, however, in that case, to send a chat text to everyone in one table I would have to pass every connected client to test if he is in the specific table. I'd rather have a list of each client in a table and call tables[ID].send("text") to send text chat. (sorry bad english)